# I cant retrieve data from web service .asmx it gives error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I run successfuly my project on my local machine. there are two projects, one of them is user panel and a web service invoked by panel...

here is the code of the user panel

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Kontrolet");
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Kontrolet()
    {
        string lbl = "";

        KONTROL.Service1SoapClient _context = new KONTROL.Service1SoapClient();
        int d;

        d= _context.GirisKontrol(Request["kullaniciadi"], Request["sifre"]);

        if (d == 0)
        {
            lbl = " 0 degeri!";
        }

        if (d == 1)
        {
            return Redirect("aaa");

 .........
```

the error is on line

```
KONTROL.Service1SoapClient _context = new KONTROL.Service1SoapClient();
```

"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server HttpPost..."

and the error page is
"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
problem is with the web service. here is the semptomes:

```
user panel: local && web service: local =>  WORKS FINE!...
user panel: server && web service: local => Failed
user panel: local && web service: server => failed
user panel: server && web service: server => failed
```

what would be to do?